# Is there something like memcheck and fdisk for android?

Tags: applications, logging

Basically I want to connect my android asus to my computer and then do fdisk and memcheck.

I suspected that the disk is not perfect and so is the memory. Sometimes it crashes with no reason.

Comment: What crashes with no reason: an app or the Android itself? fdisk is available through both busybox and toybox.

Comment: memcheck can be obtained using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck), but its description says: "*Memcheck detects memory-management problems, and is **aimed primarily at C and C++ programs***".

Comment: used to be a few apps. Now only youtube.

Comment: I want something for end customer.

Comment: I just want to check that the whole disk in my android phone is free of defect ( can be read)

Comment: At least the empty portion of the disk